# PHP MYSQL query sort per category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, output

i have the following query:

```
SELECT projects.project_name, files.file_name
FROM `projects` JOIN `files` ON (projects.project_id = files.project_id)
ORDER BY projects.project_name ASC, files.file_name ASC
```

which will for example output:

```
Project1 - file1
Project1 - file2
Project2 - file3
Project2 - file4
```

in PHP, i extract these values using:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
```

I somehow want an output like this:

```
Project1 - file1, file2
Project2 - file3, file4
```

How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that directly in `MySQL` using `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT  projects.project_name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(files.file_name) file_name
FROM    projects
        INNER JOIN files 
            ON (projects.project_id = files.project_id)
GROUP   BY projects.project_name
ORDER   BY projects.project_name ASC, 
           files.file_name ASC
```

- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

Please stop using any functions labeled mysql* mysql has been depreceated. PDO is MUCH better to work with and is being actively developed.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Notice the big red warning banner on the mysql_fetch_assoc() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php